# How to compress a file without using any external libraries?

Tags: objective-c, ios, zip

I need to be able to compress file in an iPhone/iPad application. I know there are a few libraries out there that have this problem solved and are easy to integrate in an application, but I was wondering if there is something already implemented in Cocoa. It would help me a lot if I did not need to integrate external libraries in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something in iOS / objective-c ? If so, you do know that most objects you are using is an 'external library' i.e. the Foundation framework?

There is, shipped with every iPhone, libz which is the library for zipping / unzipping. You just include it as if it were any other framework.

However, the chances that you will, first time, use it as bug free as an existing library that's been tested for years by hundreds of other developers is slim.

Personally, I would easily choose adding a library over writing my own for something like this - it's been done before, you're just wasting time re-writing it. Try [ZipArchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/downloads/list) for a one-liner to unzip files etc. Just copy the source code into your app and press build :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know that most objects are using an "external library". What I meant was something that is shipped with the standard SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is something like that in cocoa inbuild .. but you should have a look here - https://bitbucket.org/kolpanic/zipkit/wiki/Home